# Get text of multiple DOM elements to reuse later in D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm having a bit of trouble in extracting text of multiple `<legend>` elements to reuse it later in a list. I'm getting the array with whole DOM elements but can't get to only the text as per this:

```
// this works...
form.selectAll("legend").each(function(d,i) {
  console.log("text: " + i + " is " + d3.select(this).text())
})
```

Here's my code:

```
var form = d3.select("#print-form"),
    progress = d3.select("#progress"),
    steps = form.selectAll("legend").nodes();

progress
    .selectAll("li")
    .data(steps)
    .enter()
    .append("li")
    .text(function(d,i) { return d ? "Step " + (i + 1) + ": " + this.text() : "err"; });
```

HTML:

```
<ul id="progress"></ul>

<form id="print-form">
    <fieldset class="step s1">
        <legend>Print Type</legend>
        <input type="button" value="Next">
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="step s2">
        <legend>Product</legend>
        <input type="button" value="Next">
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="step s3">
        <legend>Style</legend>
        <input type="button" value="Next">
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="step s4">
        <legend>Material</legend>
        <input type="button" value="Next">
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="step s5">
        <legend>Finishing</legend>
        <input type="button" value="Next">
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="step s6">
        <legend>Delivery</legend>
        <input type="button" value="Next">
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="step s7">
        <legend>Your Details</legend>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

And [pen](https://codepen.io/znak/pen/OQBQja?editors=1011).

Where's my mistake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data bound to the li elements is an array of dom elements(nodes). So you will have to convert the variable `d` to a d3 selection to apply text function.

Change

```
return d ? "Step " + (i + 1) + ": " + this.text() : "err";
```

to

```
return d ? "Step " + (i + 1) + ": " + d3.select(d).text() : "err";
```

```js
var form = d3.select("#print-form"),
  progress = d3.select("#progress"),
  st = ["one", "two", "three"],
  steps = form.selectAll("legend").nodes();

progress
  .selectAll("li")
  .data(steps)
  .enter()
  .append("li")
  .text(function(d, i) {
    return d ? "Step " + (i + 1) + ": " + d3.select(d).text() : "err";
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<ul id="progress"></ul>

<form id="print-form">
  <fieldset class="step s1">
    <legend>Print Type</legend>
    <input type="button" value="Next">
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset class="step s2">
    <legend>Product</legend>
    <input type="button" value="Next">
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset class="step s3">
    <legend>Style</legend>
    <input type="button" value="Next">
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset class="step s4">
    <legend>Material</legend>
    <input type="button" value="Next">
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset class="step s5">
    <legend>Finishing</legend>
    <input type="button" value="Next">
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset class="step s6">
    <legend>Delivery</legend>
    <input type="button" value="Next">
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset class="step s7">
    <legend>Your Details</legend>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

I would suggest binding an array of legend texts instead of binding an array of node elements.

```
var steps = form.selectAll("legend")
  .nodes()
  .map(function(legend) {
    return d3.select(legend).text();
  });

progress
  .selectAll("li")
  .data(steps)
  .enter()
  .append("li")
  .text(function(d, i) {
    return d ? "Step " + (i + 1) + ": " + d : "err";
  });
```

Comment: Just when you thought you had seen it all... At first, I thought this was nonsense; `select(d)`—phhhh ;-) Also, mixing a string `":"` inside a ternary operator doesn't really improve readability. Good catch!

Comment: I have never seen and would never come up with `d3.select(d)`, so thanks! I wonder if I've overcomplicated things and there is a better way to do this?